# sound alert in Excel when cell changes

Tags: excel

I use a DDE feed to display a value in a cell.  I would like to create an alarm to alert when the value in the cell changes.  I am not comparing the cell with any other cell and I don't know whether the value will be higher or lower. I just want to hear a sound when the cell receives a new piece of data from the DDE feed.

Is there anyway to do this.

I know to create an alarm...I just don't know how to trigger it on a single cell changing.

Help appreciated.

Thanks.

S

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this code (just add it in the sheet module):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
       'call your alarm here
   End If
End Sub
```

this code will triggered each time something changed in the sheet. So, you can use `IF` statement to determine whether only one cell changed and call alarm in this case